# How can I fix the Keystore file not found for signing config 'debug' error?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I'm trying to setup a new react-native project but I ran into this error when I tried react-native run-android:

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningDebug'.
> Keystore file 'C:\Users\Ahers\Downloads\reactnative-beautiful-ui-master (1)\reactnative-beautiful-ui-master\android\app\debug.keystore' not found for signing config 'debug'. 

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: C:\Users\Ahers\Downloads\reactnative-beautiful-ui-master (1)\reactnative-beautiful-ui-master\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\gesturehandler\react\RNGestureHandlerButtonViewManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
```

Here's my build.grade code:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I tried running this command in order to fix it but it didn't work:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore
  -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

I'm honestly not sure what to do so I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your keystore file is either removed or changed.

You can generate it through Android studio. Use this [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing&ved=2ahUKEwiHke_YvZTqAhUIb30KHTNfA5oQFjAGegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw3x52zDW82zByuAWkfslbNq).

Comment: Hello Sir. When I hit build, those options didn't come up for me. Is there someway for me to eliminate the need for this keystore file?

Comment: Sorry sir, one cannot eliminate the keystore file to generate signed builds. If you want to generate debug builds, then there is no need.

Comment: Have you tried generating keystore through Android studio?

Comment: Hello Sir. I tried it and it worked thankfully. Thank you so much!